# Resizing specific drawing object with c#

Tags: c#, drawing

I took an Image Box (win form) of **720 X 640** and draw several objects like polygon, rectangle , line, ellipse etc.

when I click on save button, `Point (X,Y)'s` of the drawn objects are saved in database.

Now I retrieve the points and set them in a **320 X 240** image box with same proportion.

That means I have to resize specific drawing objects from **720 X 640** to **320 X 240**.

how do I resize with C#?

Comment: Screen-shots like this are incredibly useless.  There's no way to tell why you cannot use Graphics.ScaleTransform().

Comment: objects are saved as collection of points (x1,y1), (x2,y2),......,(xn,yn). and these X. Y's are set for 720 X 640 dimension. When I load this X, Y's in 320 X 240 dimension, the X, Y's will not be same as previous. Maintaing the same aspect ratio, how do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly scale the drawing you need to know old bitmap size and the new bitmap size.

```
var newX = (oldX / oldWidth) * newWidth;
var newY = (oldY / oldHeight) * newHeight;
```

If you only store the (X, Y) of points and cannot store the oldSize, then you could store PointF(oldX / oldWidth, oldY / oldHeight) and multiply the points by the dimensions of the new image.

If storing of floating point values is not available you can multiply the devision result by some big number and cast it to int and store the result. After loading divide it by the same large integer. That will cause some insignificant precision loss though.